# How to inject view in popup windows in prism

Tags: wpf, view, prism

I have a popup window which I use for editing the settings/preferences of application. This window as a tab control, each tab corresponds to settings of each module. I want each tab content to be supplied by module as a view. In the tab I created the regions but from the module when I assign this view to regions, I get a region not found exception. This is because regions added in other windows are not added in the RegionManager of shell.

My question is, how to inject views in the other windows(other than shell window).

I believe following need to be done:
1. Create a RegionManager at the root of the Options window (like in Shell.xaml)
2. From the module, get a reference to the regoin manager
3. Inject the views into it

or

1. Add the regions defined in the other window to the default RegionManager

Answer (score 1):

What kind of popup window do you use? 
You probably need to use Behavior driven popup (like in StockTrader RI "SecondRegion") and then you will be hooked into your main RegionManager since your tabbed view will be inside region.